# Non-parametric counterpart of Nested Anova with unbalanced designed

Tags: hierarchical, anova

Is there a non-parametric counterpart of Nested ANOVA with unbalanced designed? My data is not normal even after doing different transformations. Thus i could not use parametric test. I came across Friedman tests but i understand that it requires a complete and balanced design.

What I want to determine is the effect of A (e.g. gear type) in B (e.g. catch) where A is nested in factor C (e.g. study site).

I'm new to R and I am not an expert in Stat either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.